# how to get the text of anchor tag in jest

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

```
  <a href={LinkMappingUtility.getMappedWebUiLink('/#/dashboard')}
    data-id="0"
    className="nav-menu-item"
    autoFocus="true">

  {menuItem({ linkTitle: translate('sbDashboard', currentLanguage), icon: 'swn-home-icon' })}
```

**this is the anchor tag inside that i have menu item text and i want the text in enzyme**

### My Code is :

test('all menu items display the correct text', () => {

```
    const allMenuItemText = [
        { linkTitle: 'Dashboard', icon: 'swn-home-icon' },
        { linkTitle: 'Alerts', icon: 'swn-alerts-icon' },
        { linkTitle: 'Contact Management', icon: 'swn-home-icon'},
        { linkTitle: 'Reporting', icon: 'swn-home-icon' },
        { linkTitle: 'Solutions', icon: 'swn-home-icon' },
        { linkTitle: 'Integrations', icon: 'swn-home-icon' },
        { linkTitle: 'Account Settings', icon: 'swn-home-icon'},
        { linkTitle: 'Support & Training', icon: 'swn-home-icon' }           
    ];

    wrapper.find('.nav-menu-item').forEach((node, index) => {            
        expect(node.text()).toEqual(allMenuItemText[index].linkTitle);       
    })
```

output : here i am getting the empty string in return

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing just a typo, you meant to use a class selector?

```
// tag selector
wrapper.find('nav-menu-item') ...

// class selector
wrapper.find('.nav-menu-item') ...
```

Comment: no still i am getting empty string text() method is not returning the value

Comment: @SurinRanjanPanda have you tried using a snapshot to cross-check how the anchor elements are loading? Based on edits to your question, I get the feeling we don’t have a minimal, complete, verifiable example to work from.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried selecting the link title - the anchor tag is difficult to select in the testing library - so if you select the link title you are clicking it may work

```
const anchorTag = wrapper.find("my-link-title");
expect(anchorTag).toHaveAttribute("href", "https://url-test-1#");
```